# How to cache firebase/emulators directory using GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions, firebase-tools

I am using the firebase emulator to run my tests and, I received a warning about a chance of optimization using the cache system.

How I can do this?

> It appears you are running in a CI environment. You can avoid downloading the Firestore Emulator repeatedly by caching the /home/runner/.cache/firebase/emulators directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to update tool when npm package updates use something like this:

```
- name: Get Library Versions For Binary Caching
    id: cache-settings
    run: |
      echo "::set-output name=firebase-tools::$(yarn list -s --depth=0 --pattern firebase-tools | tail -n 1 | sed 's/.*@//g')"
      echo "::set-output name=firebase-tools::$(npm list -s --depth=0 | grep firebase-tools | tail -n 1 | sed 's/.*@//g')"

  - name: Cache Firebase Emulator Binaries
    uses: actions/cache@v2.1.2
    with:
      path: ~/.cache/firebase/emulators
      key: ${{ runner.os }}-firebase-${{ steps.cache-settings.outputs.firebase-tools }}
```

Comment: set-output is already deprecated:  https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/

Answer (score 16):

Define this in GitHub Actions:

```
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Cache firebase emulators
        uses: actions/cache@v4
        with:
          path: ~/.cache/firebase/emulators
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-firebase-emulators-${{ github.sha }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-firebase-emulators-
```

Then, for example, when we run this command `firebase emulators:exec --project example 'npm test'`, if the emulator is not in the cache path, it will automatically start installing.

#### First run

1. Cache is missing

[image]

2. Download emulator when running test

[image]

3. Save cache as post action of actions/cache

[image]

#### Second run

1. Cache is found and restored and download doesn't happen.

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Worked but was missing key suffix

Comment: I would propose to use 
```key: ${{ runner.os }}-firebase-emulators-${{ github.sha }}
   restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-firebase-emulators-
```. As github caches are immutable and `${{ hashFiles('~/.cache/firebase/emulators/**') }}` will return nothing on the first attempt, this will only cache the very first version of the emulators later on and not account for changes in the emulators used or version updates.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows

inside your **.github/workflows/filename.yml** include cache instructions:

```yaml
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  emulator_test:
    name: Run all tests using Firebase Emulator
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
...
# other instructions
...
      - name: Cache node modules
        id: cache-npm
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        env:
          cache-name: cache-node-modules
        with:
          # npm cache files are stored in `~/.npm` on Linux/macOS
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-
            ${{ runner.os }}-build-
            ${{ runner.os }}-

      - if: ${{ steps.cache-npm.outputs.cache-hit != 'true' }}
        name: List the state of node modules
        continue-on-error: true
        run: npm list

      - name: Cache firebase emulators
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ~/.cache/firebase/emulators
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-firebase-${{ steps.cache-npm.outputs.firebase-tools }}
...
# other instructions
...
```

Without cache instructions:
[image]

Using cache instructions.
[image]